# How to call a class already implemented class in a different JFrame?

Tags: java, netbeans

I cant figure out how to call a class that was already implemented in Login.Java(is a JFrame) in Welcome.Java(also a JFrame)

This is the class that I have called upon in Login.Java.

```
public class Session {
    public Session(String sUsername, String sPassword, String sName, String sAge, String sSex)
    {
    String Username = sUser;
    String Password = sPassword;
    String Name = sName;
    String Age = sAge;
    String Sex = sSex;
    }

}
```

This is Login.Java code implementing the class.

```
if(rs.next()) {
 Username=rs.getString("Usernames");
 Password=rs.getString("Passwords");
 Name=rs.getString("Names");
 Age=rs.getString("Ages");
 Sex=rs.getString("Sexes");

 Session S1 = new Session(Username, Password, Name, Age, Sex);

}
```

In Welcome.Java I want to call upon S1 like so.

```
S1.Name
```

or

```
S1.Username
```

Comment: Please write descriptive variable names... It's hard to understand what's going on with `A`, `U`, `W`, etc... Also please follow Java naming conventions `firstWordLowerCaseVariables`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethods()`, `FirstWordUpperCaseClass` and `ALL_WORDS_UPPER_CASE_CONSTANTS` and use them consistently. Are you referring to `Point A` or `String A` or which `A` class? Also, read about encapsulation and MVC pattern...

Comment: I'm sorry I'm still a novice programmer. I am trying to call the class Session (implemented as S1 on JFrame1) in JFrame2.

Comment: Please follow my above recommendations and [edit] your question and write a clearer question, si we can help you

Answer (score 0):

If the S1 Session class instance is a private member of the Login (extends JFrame) class, there is no regular way to access the S1 member from outside the Login class.  You need to use public accessor methods (setters and getters).

If you want to access Login's S1 object from the Welcome class, then you need to pass a reference to the Welcome constructor, and/or Login's S1 member needs to have public visibility.

`Welcome welcome = new Welcome(login.getS1())`

Answer (score 0):

keep in mind that organising your code like this (Subclassing JFrame, public fields instead of getters in Session class) is considered bad practice in java. This is the simplest working example.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            final Wellcome app = new Wellcome();
            app.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            app.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}

class Wellcome extends JFrame {

    public Wellcome() throws HeadlessException {
        setSize(300, 300);
        final JButton loginBtn = new JButton();
        loginBtn.setAction(new AbstractAction("Login") {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                final Login login = new Login();
                final Session session = login.logIn();
                // use you session as you wish
                System.out.println(session.username);
            }
        });
        final JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.add(loginBtn);
        setContentPane(contentPane);
    }
};

class Login extends JDialog {
    private final JTextField username;
    private final JTextField password;
    private final JTextField age;

    public Login() {
        setModalityType(ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 2));
        username = addField("User", new JTextField());
        password = addField("Password", new JPasswordField());
        age = addField("Age", new JTextField());
        pack();
    }

    private JTextField addField(String name, JTextField field) {
        add(new JLabel(name));
        add(field);
        return field;
    }

    public Session logIn() {
        setVisible(true);
        return new Session(username.getText(), password.getText(), age.getText());
    }

};

class Session {
    public final String username;
    public final String password;
    public final String age;


    public Session(String username, String password, String age) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.age = age;
    }

}
```